# How can I skip commands from running if row doesn't meet some criteria?

Tags: pyspark

I have some code like the following that runs ok:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jsonString="""
  [
    {
      "person_id": 1,
      "address": {
        "line1": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
      }
    }
  ]
"""
df=spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_json(jsonString))

df1=(df
  .select(col("person_id"), explode(col("address")))
  .select(col("person_id"), col("*"))
  # other commands
)
df1.collect()

# Out[1] [Row(person_id=1, person_id=1, key='line1', value={'foo': 'bar'})]
```

However, if my dataset is an empty list, I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jsonString="""
  [
    {
      "person_id": 1,
      "address": []
    }
  ]
"""
df=spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_json(jsonString))

df1=(df
  .select(col("person_id"), explode(col("address")))

  # how can I skip all commands from here for rows where address is an empty list?
  .select(col("person_id"), col("col.*"))
  # other commands
)

# AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(col)`.
```

How can I stop the command `.select(col("person_id"), col("col.*"))` and all subsequent commands running if the address is empty?

Comment: Did you tried to use `when` and `otherwise` ? When trying to reproduce it I couldn't create the first `df`, no problem if I create the `df` with a `schema`.

Comment: Also, If when filled the `address` is a dict, when no `address` is given maybe you should give it a empty dict: `{}`; this is needed if the `df` is created with a `schema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, after multiple attempts (and comments):

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, ArrayType, StringType, MapType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jsonString1 = """
  [
    {
      "person_id": 1,
      "address": {}
    }
  ]
"""

jsonString2 = """
  [
    {
      "person_id": 1,
      "address": {
        "line1": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
      }
    }
  ]
"""

# Define a schema so no error is given when `address` is empty
schema = StructType([
    StructField("person_id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField(
      "address", 
      MapType(
        StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType())), True)
])
pdf = pd.read_json(jsonString1)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf, schema=schema)

df1 = (df
       .select(col("person_id"), col("address"))
       .withColumn(
           "tmp",
           when(size(col("address")) > 0,  # use when for the case address is empty
                col("address")).otherwise(
               lit(None).cast(   
MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
)
       )
       .select(col("person_id"), explode(col("tmp")).alias("key", "exploded_address"))
       .select(col("person_id"), col("exploded_address"))
       # other commands
       )

df1.collect()
```

the `jsonString1` output is `[]`, the `jsonString2` is `[Row(person_id=1, exploded_address={'foo': 'bar'})]` .